# Get a quantity of elements from a folder in C

Tags: c, windows, file, directory

The thing is that i want to get the number of elements from a specific folder.

Its posible?

I've made this:
Is a good practice?
Is there any function?

```
   main(){

char path[6]="#.txt";
int i=49,a=1,c=0;
//for 9 elements
while(a){
path[0]=i;
if(fopen(path,"r")){
    c++;
    printf("%i",c);
}
else 
    a=0;
i++;
}


printf("%i",c);

getch();
}
```

Comment: On which platform are you working?

Comment: You need to provide *your* code first.

Comment: @Beginner How can i provide a code if i dont know how? :( sorry

Comment: what about homework tag?

Comment: @Beginner Is not homework :( but if i put the homework tag and someone will give me a hint, thanks.

Comment: No, I do not think someone will give you a hint. You should provide some code, google for documentation try out something by yourself. If you fail, then try something easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your hint: [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx)

The number of times the return value is `TRUE` is the number of matching files.